# Swift 3 - two actions at the same time

Tags: macos, methods, swift3, action

I have a real bad problem and I have no idea how to figure it out. I'd like to perform two actions in my macOS Application: when i click button it opens a new window and in the same time performs a method (which changes the value of the label in the same view controller where the button is). But when i click, it only opens new window without execution of that method.

Here is my code:

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var button1: NSButton!
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    makeItHappen()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

func makeItHappen() {
    label1.stringValue = "Is it done?"
}
```

}

And of course I ctrl-drag from button to new window ;)

Thanks for help!

Comment: How are you triggering the opening of the new window ?  Could it to be a modal presentation segue ?  Or, if you're using a gesture recognizer, there are parameters on them to prevent further processing of the event in the rest of the responder chain.  In short, i would help to describe both calling mechanism so we can see if there are any potential conflicts

Comment: I'd like to open new window and execute block code in the same time after clicking the button. Is there any option to deal with it using threads?